# Как вынести столбцы DataGrid в стиль

Tags: wpf, xaml

В программе используется несколько `DataGrid` с одинаковым набором столбцов. 
Их достаточно много, поэтому не хочется просто копировать код.

Подскажите, можно ли вынести в стиль только лишь столбцы?

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="DataGrid.Columns">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Product.Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Product.Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Product.Price}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

### Update

В программе пользователю доступно 3 таблицы с товарами: общая, избранное и черный список.

Общая таблица:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" >
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Открыть в браузере" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                    Command="{Binding ResultsVM.OpenProductCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Добавить в избранное" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                    Command="{Binding ResultsVM.PutToFavoritesCommand, IsAsync=True}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Убрать из избранного" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                    Command="{Binding ResultsVM.RemoveFromFavoritesCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Добавить в черный список" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                    Command="{Binding ResultsVM.PutToBlackListCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Убрать из черного списка" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                    Command="{Binding ResultsVM.RemoveFromBlacklistCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Удалить" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                    Command="{Binding ResultsVM.DeleteCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Product.Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Product.Title}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Product.Price}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Избранное:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Favorites}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Открыть в браузере"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                      Command="{Binding ResultsVM.OpenProductCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Убрать из избранного" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                      Command="{Binding ResultsVM.RemoveFromFavoritesCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Удалить" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                      Command="{Binding ResultsVM.DeleteCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Product.Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Product.Title}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Product.Price}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Может быть, вам нужен `UserControl`? Что в таблицах будет _разное_?

Comment: @VladD, Да, в таблицах разные элементы.

Comment: Только заполнение разное, а остальное одинаковое?

Comment: @VladD, Контекстное меню у элементов разное.

Comment: Ох. А покажите пример двух `DataGrid`'ов, как они у вас сейчас в коде? С контекстными меню.

Comment: @VladD, Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Ага, понял. А вот контекстные меню я бы добавлял через стиль. Стиль можно сделать свойством `UserControl`'а. Я напишу завтра, сегодня уже поздно.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, посмотрите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас одинаково устроенные `DataFrid`'ы  и лишь разные данные в них, я бы вынес из в отдельный `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourProject.ProductTable"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Product.Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Product.Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Product.Price}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Заодно в code-behind `UserControl`'а можно вынести процедуры, относящиеся к этому `DataGrid`'у.

---

Пример кода для контекстного меню:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourProject.ProductTable"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              ContextMenu="{Binding GridContextMenu,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Product.Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Product.Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Product.Price}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class ProductTable : UserControl
{
    public ProductTable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ContextMenu GridContextMenu
    {
        get { return (ContextMenu)GetValue(GridContextMenuProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridContextMenuProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridContextMenuProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "GridContextMenu", typeof(ContextMenu), typeof(ProductTable));
}
```

Мы привязали контекстное меню к свойству `GridContextMenu` (потому что свойство `ContextMenu` уже занято), так что можно пользоваться так:

```
<local:ProductTable DataContext="{Binding Favorites}">
    <local:ProductTable.GridContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Открыть в браузере"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                      Command="{Binding ResultsVM.OpenProductCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Убрать из избранного" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                      Command="{Binding ResultsVM.RemoveFromFavoritesCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Удалить" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}" 
                      Command="{Binding ResultsVM.DeleteCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </local:ProductTable.GridContextMenu>
</local:ProductTable>
```

(Ну и да, установку контекстного меню можно без проблем вынести в стиль.)